# Android Studio not regenerating R.java; Gradle can't find assembleDebug task

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I pulled some recent changes from my git repo, and suddenly, Android Studio was throwing up `token not found` errors for R.java. I hit "Make Project" in Android Studio, thinking a new build would fix these errors, when instead I got this:

```
Information:Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 5 sec
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Error:Gradle: 

FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.



* What went wrong:

Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'project'.



* Try:

Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

Error:Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

The fact that it won't compile explains the problems with R.java, but I'm mystified about the problems Gradle is having. Any help?

[Edit:] I booted into Linux and noticed that it didn't have the same issue. I also noticed under Project Properties that, in Windows there are no linked Gradle projects but in Linux, the project is listed as a linked project. Unfortunately, [this tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/jetgradle-tool-window.html) to help me fix my issues apparently doesn't exist in Android Studio, only in IntelliJ proper.

Answer (score 3):

Just close everything and Restart the Android Studio and compile once again. I faced the same problem many times. It worked for me !

Comment: Not worked for me. Any other solutions? I updated the Android studio to 0.2.0 and changed nothing of my project, and this problem jumped out. Is there a simple way to rollback to previous version?

Comment: Yes, that helped me.  But I am not sure why.  Perhaps re-importing the project in Android Studio will have the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I got it resolved my setting to the correct JDK folder path.

Also make sure you have "JAVA_HOME" environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Closing Android Studio and opening it again solved my problem.